# Wrong links in ToC when using \xpretocmd command

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex

I've noticed that I have wrong links in the ToC when I use a command to reset the section counter within a part in a report document (I haven't tried with another document). Links go to the first "part" of the document, and ignore the rest. Clearly, `\xpretocmd` is messing with some internal counter. I've read plenty on the `\phantomsection`, but it applies to unnumbered sections.

I want the "sections" within "part" to be numbered without referring to the part (it's too long), and starting from the beginning when entering a new "part". Any idea how I can achieve that behaviour ?  Here's a minimal example that has the weird behaviour mentionned.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
%% define usepackage
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % "Computer Modern" modern font
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Include images
\usepackage[english]{babel} % Handling english.
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xpatch}
%% --- end define usepackage ---


%% Changing The naming of the parts, section, subsections and subsubsections
\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}} % \part as roman numerals
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % Removing part name from section and subsection
\xpretocmd{\part}{\setcounter{section}{0}}{}{} %Setting section counter to zero when entering a part


%% Infos
\title{A good title}
\author{Some Guy}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

    \part{The first part}

        \section{The first section}

            \subsection{A subsection}
            Foo
            \subsection{Another one}
            Bar

    \part{The second part}
        \section{A first section}
            \subsection{My mind is blown}
            FooBar
            \subsection{So is mine !}
            BarFoo

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `xpatch` for this, but

```
\counterwithin*{section}{part}
```

which will also fix the problem with links, because it modifies `\theHsection` for you (see the manual of `hyperref`). Thanks to Ulrike for pointing it out.

You might do it with `\xpretocmd`, but it's overkill and would also need `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}` in order to get unique anchors.

I also recommend to load `bookmark` and to modify the page numbering for the title page, or there would be a duplicate page link.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{report}
%% define usepackage
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% no longer needed
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}    % "Computer Modern" modern font
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Include images
%\usepackage[english]{babel} % Handling english. (not needed)
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
%% --- end define usepackage ---


%% Changing The naming of the parts, section, subsections and subsubsections
%\renewcommand{\thepart}{\Roman{part}} % \part as roman numerals (is default)
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}} % Removing chapter number from section and subsection

\counterwithin*{section}{part}

%% Infos
\title{A good title}
\author{Some Guy}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{alph}
\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents

\part{The first part}

\section{The first section}

\subsection{A subsection}

Foo

\subsection{Another one}

Bar

\part{The second part}

\section{A first section}

\subsection{My mind is blown}

FooBar

\subsection{So is mine!}

BarFoo

\end{document}
```

Note that parts use Roman numerals by default. Instead `\thesection` uses `\thechapter` which is what you want to remove.

If you want that the table of contents is page 2, remove `\pagenumbering{alph}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}`, replacing the latter with `\setcounter{page}{2}`.

Comment: the `\renewcommand{\theHsection}{\thepart.\arabic{section}}` is not needed here. hyperref resets \theHsection if you call \@addtoreset.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for recalling it.

Comment: @egreg Why would `\xpretocmd` be overkill ?

Comment: @Theragondin Because the action can be performed with no additional package. And patching should be a last resort.